# convert XML via XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML

**EDITED:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xsl.xslt"?> 
<CATALOG>
<CD>        
</CD>   
</CATALOG>
```

I have XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
<xsl:output exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="*">      
<xsl:element name="{lower-case(local-name())}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to check the output I Think it should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<catalog>
<cd>        
</cd>   
</catalog>
```

Where I can check or verify that output is correct or not. Do I need to use any tool for this?

Comment: Have you checked the online resources? For example this page seems to do exactly what you need: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/online_xslt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xsl.xslt"?>
```

to your xml file under the xml dec and open it in a web browser.

Comment: Hi Ryet0, I modified <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xsl.xslt"?>. Its not working is this correct?

Comment: This won't work. The stylesheet is XSLT 2.0 and won't run in the browser. @user965884 - You'd be better off using a 2.0 processor like Saxon, or AltovaXML. Better yet use a good IDE like oXygen or XMLSpy (which is what was used to create the XML).

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in top of the XML Data and run that in the Browser.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Your_xslt_file.xsl"?>
```

Let me know if this helps.. :)